# Countable subset of countable space

Tags: general-topology

Let X be a topological space which has a countable base for its open sets. let A be a subset of X which is discrete in the relative topology. Prove that A is countable.

I’m not really sure what to do here. Since A is discrete can I just take the basis of singletons and have those be countable?
What to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\mathcal{B}$ be a countable base for $X$. For each $a \in A$, $\{a\}$ is open in $A$ so $\{a\} = O_a \cap A$ for some open subset $O_a$ of $X$. As we have a base, there is some $B_a \in \mathcal{B}$ such that $$a \in B_a \subseteq O_a$$

which implies that $$B_a \cap A = \{a\}$$

and this in turn implies that the map $a \to B_a$ from $A$ into $\mathcal{B}$ is injective. And a set that has an injection into a countable set is also countable. So $A$ is countable.